# How to cut a range of lines defined by variables

Tags: shell, awk, range, cut

I have this python crawler output

```
[+] Site to crawl: http://www.example.com
[+] Start time: 2020-05-24 07:21:27.169033
[+] Output file: www.example.com.crawler

[+] Crawling
   [-] http://www.example.com
   [-] http://www.example.com/
   [-] http://www.example.com/icons/ubuntu-logo.png
   [-] http://www.example.com/manual
    [i] 404 Not Found
[+] Total urls crawled: 4

[+] Directories found:
   [-] http://www.example.com/icons/
[+] Total directories: 1

[+] Directory with indexing
```

I want to cut the lines between "Crawling" & "Total urls crawled" using awk or any other tool, so basically i wanna use variables to assign the NR to the first keyword "Crawling", and a second variable assigned to it the NR value of the second limiter "Total urls crawled", and then cut the range between the two, i tried something like this:

```
awk 'NR>$(Crawling) && NR<$(urls)' file.txt
```

but nothing really worked, the best i got is a cut from the Crawling+1 line to the end of the file which isn't helpfull really, so how to do it and how to cut a range of lines with awk with variables!

## awk

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I got your requirement correctly you want to put shell variables to `awk` code and search strings then try following.

```
awk -v crawl="Crawling" -v url="Total urls crawled" '
$0 ~ url{
  found=""
  next
}
$0 ~ crawl{
  found=1
  next
}
found
'  Input_file
```

Explanation: Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk -v crawl="Crawling" -v url="Total urls crawled" '   ##Starting awk program and setting crawl and url values of variables here.
$0 ~ url{                      ##Checking if line is matched to url variable then do following.
  found=""                     ##Nullify the variable found here.
  next                         ##next will skip further statements from here.
}
$0 ~ crawl{                    ##Checking if line is matched to crawl variable then do following.
  found=1                      ##Setting found value to 1 here.
  next                         ##next will skip further statements from here.
}
found                          ##Checking condition if found is SET(NOT NULL) then print current line.
'  Input_file                  ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Answer (score 1):

The clause "...or any other tool" prompts me to point out that a scripting language could be used in command-line mode for this. Here's how it could be done using Ruby, where `'t'` is the name of the file that contains the text from which the specified lines are to be extracted. The following would be entered in the shell.

```
ruby -W0 -e 'puts STDIN.readlines.select { |line| true if line.match?(/\bCrawling\b/)..line.match?(/\bTotal urls crawled\b/) }[1..-2]' < t
```

displays the following:

```
["   [-] http://www.example.com",
 "   [-] http://www.example.com/",
 "   [-] http://www.example.com/icons/ubuntu-logo.png",
 "   [-] http://www.example.com/manual",
 "    [i] 404 Not Found"]
```

The following operations are performed.

- `STDIN.readlines` and `< t` reads the lines of `t` into an array
- `select` selects the lines for which its block calculation returns `true`
- `[1..-2]` extracts all but the first and last of the selected lines

`select`'s block calculation,

```
true if line.match?(/\bCrawling\b/)..line.match?(/\bTotal urls crawled\b/)
```

employs the [*flip-flop* operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flip-flop_(programming)). The block returns `nil` (treated as `false` by Ruby) until a line that matches `/\bCrawling\b` is read, namely, `"[+] Crawling"`. The block then returns `true`, and continues to return `true` until and it encounters the line matching `/\bTotal urls crawled\b`, namely, `"[+] Total urls crawled: 4"`. The block returns `true` for that line as well, but returns `false` for each subsequent line until and if it encounters another line that matches `/\bCrawling\b`, in which case the process repeats. Hence, "flip-flop".

`"-W0"` in the command line suppresses warning messages. Without it one may see the warning, "flip-flop is deprecated" (depending on the version of Ruby being used). After a decision was made to deprecate the (rarely-used) flip-flop operator, Rubyists took to the streets with pitchforks and torches in protest. The Ruby monks saw the error of their ways and reversed their decision.